# java SQLquery Error

Tags: java, sql

I keep getting an sql exception when I try to run this command although the fields in the data base are correct, same as `email_chauffeur` and `password`

```
public Chauffeur findChauffeurByEmailPwd(String email, String pwd) {
        Chauffeur c = null;


        try {
            String req = "select * from chauffeur where email_chauffeur='" + email + "' and pwd='" + pwd + "'";
            DataSource ds = DataSource.getInstance();
            connection = ds.getConnection();
            Statement s = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(req);
             if(rs.isBeforeFirst()){
                rs.next();
            c.setIdChauffeur(rs.getInt("id_chauffeur"));
            c.setNomUser(rs.getString("nom_chauffeur"));
            c.setPrenomUser(rs.getString("prenom_chauffeur"));
            c.setCinUser(rs.getString("cin_chauffeur"));
            c.setTelUser(rs.getInt("tel_chauffeur"));
            c.setEmailUser(rs.getString("email_chauffeur"));
            c.setPwdUser(rs.getString("pwd"));
            c.setAdresseUser(rs.getString("adresse_chauffeur"));
            c.setNote(rs.getInt("note_chauffeur"));
            c.setNotifUser(rs.getInt("notif_chauffeur"));
             }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ChauffeurDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return c;

    }
```

The error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'email_chaffeur' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: 'email_chaffeur' <> 'email_chauffeur' (il manque un "u" / a "u" is missing)

Comment: Spelling error...email_chaffeur.  You have email_cha**u**ffeur

Comment: You might also want to read about sql injection.. And you should close connections, etc

Comment: Check that the column email_chauffeur exists in the chauffeur table. Make sure you spell it correctly. That said, you are exposing yourself to SQL injection. In addition,  You would be better of storing a salted hash of the password using SHA256 for example. Storing passwords in plain text is not a good idea.

Comment: but it 'email_chaffeur' doesn't exist in my code. It was like that before but I changed it. However, it keeps showing me the same error.

Comment: @RC. tu dois publier une response / you must publish an answer.

Comment: Wait, you mean that with your current code you get the error message with chaffeur instead of chauffeur? If so, it means your code does not recompile and you are using an the compiled class of the previous code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza it's barely one, this should be closed as a typo IMHO (it's "une reponse" ;o)

Comment: @RC it's just a test. Not a project or something.

Comment: You mean a *test*, not an *essay*.

Comment: @Tarik exactly. I keep getting email_chaffeur in the error even that all my fields are email_chauffeur

Comment: Probably the error is in another query. I would debug or use log messages to identify the location of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running outdated compiled code. Delete all compiled .class files and force a rebuild.

Comment: Please, take my warnings about SQL injection and clear text passwords seriously.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the error message, the executed code is using a column named "email_chaffeur" but there's no such column in the database. It looks like you have a typo in your code.

My advice, fix the typo(s), redeploy the code.

You might also want to read about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and close the resources used (like [`Connection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html), etc)